# In java I have a float value that I am left justifying but its supposed to be a money value and the $ sign won't move to the left

Tags: java, floating-point, printf

How do I move the $ symbol at the same time as the float value that I am formatting with printf?

```
System.out.printf("$%20.2f\n", booksTotal );
```

It ends up looking like

```
"$               10.00"
 ↑
```

instead of

```
"               $10.00"
                ↑
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("%20s$%.2f%n", " ", booksTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to first create proper string representing numerical value with dollar sight:

`String.format("$%.2f", booksTotal)` -> `"$10.00"`

and then place it in your column

```
System.out.printf("%21s%n", String.format("$%.2f", booksTotal)); 
//                   ^20+1 since previous pattern had one place reserved for $
```

Also consider using `%n` instead of `\n` if you want to have OS dependant line separator (like `\r\n` for Windows).

Demo (added `'` for clarity, you will need to remove it):

```
System.out.printf("'%21s'%n", String.format("$%.2f", 123d));
System.out.printf("'%21s'%n", String.format("$%.2f", 32.213));
System.out.printf("'%21s'%n", String.format("$%.2f", 1d));
```

result:

```
'              $123,00'
'               $32,21'
'                $1,00'
```